# R plotting mean + SD of a continuous data

Tags: r, plot, graph, mean

I have some continuous data:

- mean_force - 2700 values reflecting a change of my dependent varibale
  through 2700 ms
- sd_force - another 2700 values, a standard deviation of the dependent
  variable through time

I'm plotting mean_force on a graph, like here:

```
    x=c(1:2700)
    plot(x, mean_force, ty="l", col="blue", ylim=c(-15, 15),
    ylab="force (mN)", 
    xlab='time (ms)',
    lty=1,lwd=3)
```

The question is how can I plot SD as well, the way it was done on the picture below (shaded area around the mean)? Is there any simple way to do it in R?

[image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PIC]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add shaded confidence intervals to line plot with specified values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743503/how-to-add-shaded-confidence-intervals-to-line-plot-with-specified-values)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I don't think it's a duplicate, because the OP here is using base R, while the other question asked about ggplot

Comment: @camille You are right, I will retract the close vote. Thanks, SO will have a new answered question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a base graphics solution, maybe this will work for your:

```
#create data
x<-1:100
mean_force<-0.5*x+rnorm(100)
#assume constant standard deviation across the 
sd<-5
#determine error band
psd<-mean_force+sd
nsd<-mean_force-sd

plot(x, mean_force, ty="l", col="blue", 
     ylab="force (mN)", 
     xlab='time (ms)',
     lty=1,lwd=3)
#draw boundary and fill
lines(x, psd)
lines(x, nsd)
polygon(x=c(x, rev(x)), y=c(psd, rev(nsd)), col="lightblue", density = 40, angle=90)
#redraw line on top
lines(x, mean_force, col="blue",lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's great!